# Python if statements always go to else

Tags: python, python-3.x

Code always goes to the else statement regardless of number 1, 2, or 3

```
print("Finally learning about input in order to get info from the user")
numbers1 = input("Please Choose a Number from 1 to 3: ")
print(numbers1)
if numbers1 == 1:
    print("This number would result in failure on future games")
elif numbers1 == 2:
    print("This would be a success in any future game created by user")
elif numbers1 == 3:
    print("Massive Faulure")
else:
    print("Game Will Result IN Failure")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

any input from keyboard is taken is as a string.  Just convert it before you compare it to an integer...

```
numbers1 = int(numbers1)
....
```

Comment: Thanks I thought it was able to do integers as well